# Any web apps that can keep track of a wine cellar?

Tags: webapp-rec

I like wine.  I have a small cellar and track my use of it with pen and paper.

Some of the functions I'm looking for in a web app include:

- update and access tasting notes
- check my cellar stock from PDA when shopping
- upload label images (OCR an awesome bonus)
- share recommendations with friends
- integrate with an auction site for items I want to buy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Vincellar](http://vincellar.vinfolio.com/do/vincellar/home) seems to provide most of your desired features (I never used it though).

Alternatives I found:

- [Vinote](http://www.vinote.com/)
- [MyWineAssistant](http://www.mywineassistant.com/)
- [Unicellar](http://www.unicellar.com/)
- [Yourcellar](http://www.youcellar.com/en/)

Comment: Response appreciated - I will check those out.